# Dynamic space allocation for a stack (JAVA)

Tags: java, oop, dynamic, stack

I have a programming assignment on Data Structures & Algorithms, and one of the tasks was to

> *"Prompt the user for the size of the character stack (M) at runtime and dynamically     allocate space for the user stack in the system stack. **You specifically may not use "new, malloc," or any other operator, which allocates space in the heap in any language.**"*

I'm new to data structures, and was wondering if the following code I wrote fits the requirements?

Code:

```
public class DynamicStack
{
    private char[]  array;
    private int     top = 0;    // Array counter
    private int     size;       // Array size

    private final double CAPACITY_CHANGE_RATE = 1.3; // Stack resize ratio

    ....
    All other methods: push(), pop(), peek(), and etc.
    ....

    private void ensureCapacity()
    {
        if (isFull()) {
            size = (int) Math.ceil(size * CAPACITY_CHANGE_RATE);
            char[] oldArray = array;
            array = new char[size];
            System.arraycopy(oldArray, 0, array, 0, oldArray.length);
        }
    }
}
```

Technically, whatever I use inside a non-static method has to be allocated in a new system stack and not go in the heap, right?

Comment: Since you're using the `new` operator in `array = new char[size];` your code does not fit the requirements.

Answer (score 4):

> Technically, whatever I use inside a non-static method has to be allocated in a new system stack and not go in the heap, right?

If you are asking if everything *will be* allocated on the stack, then the answer (in Java) is:  No - that is NOT correct.

For instance `array = new char[size]` allocates the char array from the Heap.  In Java `new` *always* allocates from the Heap.

In fact, I don't think you can write this program in Java ... given those constraints.  Try C or C++.

Comment: The assignment specifically mentioned "You may use C++, Ada, Perl, Java, PHP, and Cobol." I suppose the professor made a mistake?

Comment: Originally was my answer, but better as a comment to your answer [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/jls7.pdf) §17.4.1 says:

"All instance fields, static fields, and array elements are stored in heap memory"

Comment: @LinarGarifullin - I think it would be worthwhile clarifying this with the professor.  Maybe he *meant to say* that individual stack cells cannot be allocated on the heap.  But yea, on the face of it, it looks like a mistake.  (It is certainly a rather "interesting" mix of languages ...)

Comment: Just talked to my professor. He said several students have completed the lab, and it is very much possible. So I'm sorry I can't accept the answer..